# How can I run this docker image in detached mode, and export the port 3000 so I can view locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

All the examples I see online are using docker-compose, but I want to try and run this simple rails application (no db needed) using just the docker run command.

I want to expose the port 3000 so I can view it locally on my laptop in the browser on the same port.

I have this Dockerfile so far:

```
FROM ruby:2.6-alpine

RUN apk update && apk --update add \
 build-base \
 nodejs \
 postgresql-dev \
 tzdata \
 imagemagick

# yarn
ENV PATH=/root/.yarn/bin:$PATH
RUN apk add --virtual build-yarn curl && \
    touch ~/.bashrc && \
    curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | sh && \
    apk del build-yarn


RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN gem update --system
RUN gem install bundler


COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install --binstubs

CMD ["./puma -C config/puma.rb"]
```

I was able to build the docker image so far using:

```
docker build -t my-rails .
```

What command should I use to run the rails app, detached, exposing the port now?

Comment: In that Dockerfile, you need to either split the `CMD` into multiple words `CMD ["puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]` or use shell form `CMD puma -C config/puma.rb`; in the form you have it now it gets treated as a single quoted word.  Depending on what you need Yarn for you might use a separate `node` container; shell dot files like `.bashrc` are one of the things that don't really work well in Docker.

Answer (score 1):

To run your app in docker run the below command

```
docker run -d -p 3000:8080(your app port) -v host_volume_or_directory:container_volume -t image_name:tag
```

just change the port as per your needs, first port will be used with your host machine ip to get the application frontend or this is a expose port. remove the  volume part from -v if you don't have any volume to mount. -d means for detached mode.

Comment: I don't have a volume? Not sure what -v is doing.

Comment: then please remove " -v host_volume_or_directory:container_volume"  part and run

Comment: I added the host like ```-v /path/to/rails/app:/app``` but when I run it, and go to localhost:3000 I just get an error "localhost didn’t send any data."

Comment: can you see  that container running status in the output of "docker ps  -a "? can you check the logs using "docker logs -f container_id" ?

Comment: In my case, I need to use docker ip address starting from 192.168.x.x instead of localhost. could you please check whether your docker has dedicated IP address

Comment: docker ps shows it is up, the command shows 'irb' is that correct?

Comment: ```fc5af4fdaa85        my-rails:latest   "irb"                    23 seconds ago      Up 22 seconds                  0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   magical_villani```

Comment: yes you have to use host machine IP instead of localhost. IP 0.0.0.0 means any ip of the host machin.
Please change your CMD ["./puma -C config/puma.rb"]  to CMD ["puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"] and rebuild the image and run again.

Comment: I am running locally, what is my host ip other than localhost?

Comment: please run "ifconfig" for linux based os and "ipconfig" for windows